# How to write a RewriteRule to match a not existing file?

Tags: mod-rewrite, rewrite

How can I write a `RewriteRule` that first checks if the requested file exists, and if not, redirects to the root page:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule "^/(.*)" "/" [L]
```

For example
`http://example.com/not_existing_file`
should redirect to `http://example.com`.

This doesn't work however.
What's wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule "^/(.*)" "/" [L]
> ```

Your *condition*, checking that the request does *not* map to an existing file, would seem to be correct. However, your `RewriteRule` does not *redirect*, it *internally rewrites* the request instead. It would also seem to trigger a rewrite loop (500 error)?

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/. / [R=302,L]
```

The `R` flag is required here in order to trigger an *external redirect*. This would only redirect `/<something>`, rather than `/<anything>`, as in your original code.

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to `301` (permanent) once you are sure this is working OK - if that is what's required. Makes for easier testing, since 301s are otherwise cached *hard* by the browser.

This also assumes this is in the main server config, not `.htaccess` or `<Directory>` section.